# Form Subreport Print in Access 2016

Tags: vba, ms-access

So I have this form where I have two textboxes that filter the data of a subreport presented in the form by month and location so it brings me to the record I want of the subreport.

This all works great I'm able to see the report and when I filter using the textboxes it shows the data I want. The textboxes basically just change the RecordSource of the subreport thus giving me the information I'm looking for.

The problem is when I try to print the report with a button on the form. It prints the wrong data. I noticed that when I save the form and close it then open it up again and try to print it does print the data I searched for before closing the report in the first place.

I'm guessing somehow access filters the data into the subreport and not the report itself and when I try to print the data from the report not the subreport on the form the report doesnt have the data yet.

So how can I print the subreport and not the report?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I thought Me.Child13.Report would work but no luck. I also tried Me.Child13.SourceObject but this ends up with the report name being Report.Report1 instead of just Report1 and gives me an error.

Comment: I found a workaround for this. What I did was to use 2 reports report1 would be the one used in the form as a subreport and report2 is the one used to print since I cant have report 1 opened to save its record source at the same time it is opened in the form as a subreport. So then i save both reports record source to the filter I apply on the form and use one report to show to the user and the other report for print.